# Read installer version from an .ini file stored in the same directory in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to distribute the compiled installer with a separate INI file. The setup will load configurations (e.g. a version) from an INI file supplied to that particular client.

I have a `ver.ini` file in the same directory as the `Setup.exe`. It contains-

```
[Version]
Ver=0.0.11
```

I want to use it like-

```
#define AppVer ReadIni("ver.ini", "Version", "Ver", "unknown")
```

The Problem: Inno Setup is showing `AppVer` as `unknown`, rather than `0.0.11`.

If I use a hard-coded file path for the `ver.ini` file, it works:

```
#define AppVer ReadIni("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ver.ini", "Version", "Ver", "unknown")
```

Since I'm distributing the Setup to my customers, I cannot use a hard-coded file path.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/). The preprocessor is executed on compile time. So even if you fix the path problem (e.g. using `SourcePath` [preprocessor variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars)), it won't help, as you will be reading INI file on the machine that *compiles* your installer. Not on the machine, where the installer is *executed*.

---

You have to use Pascal Scripting and a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants). Use [`GetIniString` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getinistring) to read the INI file and [`src` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) to refer to the source directory.

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={code:GetAppVersion}
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetAppVersion(Param: string): string;
var
  IniPath: string;
begin
  IniPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\ver.ini');
  Result := GetIniString('Version', 'Ver', 'Unknown', IniPath);
end;
```

---

You may want to abort the installation in case the version cannot be found:

```pascal
function GetAppVersion(Param: string): string;
var
  IniPath: string;
begin
  IniPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\ver.ini');
  Result := GetIniString('Version', 'Ver', '', IniPath);
  if Result = '' then RaiseException('Cannot find version');
end;
```